# Flutter: How to display a short text file from assets on screen of phone?

Tags: flutter, text-files, display

I have ckecked all the answers about reading and writing file in Flutter. None of them answers the question of how to display a text file on the screen of the phone.

All I want to do is to have a function/method to call with the filename as input, which will display a short text file from my assets directory on a new screen on the phone that I have navigated to. The file is correctly placed in assets and mentioned in the yaml file. I have seen the suggestion to use:

```
Future loadAsset() async {
return await rootBundle.loadString('assets/my_text.txt');
}
```

but I don't know how to use it and what code to use to display a file on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that you know how to display a Text on the Screen, so I will just try to explain how I normally read files.

First you have to import:

```
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'dart:io';
```

and then, in your class, you can use this:

```
Future<void> readMyFile() async {
  Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  var _localFilePath = (directory.path + "yourfile.txt");

     if (FileSystemEntity.typeSync(_localFilePath) == FileSystemEntityType.file) {
       final myFile = await _localFile(_localFilePath);
       List<String> linesAsList = await myFile.readAsLinesSync();

    for (var i = 0; i < linesAsList.length; i++) {
      //print("Line No: " + i.toString() + "\n");
      print(linesAsList[i]);
    }
  }
}

Future<File> _localFile(String myPath) async {
  return File(myPath);
}
```

At the end, the content of your file is in linesAsList as a list of lines.

Comment: Celt K.B.: Can you tell me what is wrong with my code above?

Comment: In your code, you never call the function  readMyFile().
I think, you should have something like:
       ReadFile yourReader = ReadFile(fileName: 'myfile.txt');
        yourReader.readMyFile();

Comment: That helped. It now calls readMyFile. I can see that, since I added a print statement to console. But it doesn't display the myfile.txt on the screen. How can that be done?

Comment: In readMyFile I also tried to change "myfile.txt" to fileName (without quotes. Isn't that correct to do? I need that for more small files to print. BTW shouldn't it have been single quotes around myfile.txt in your code?

Comment: On the line: List linesAsList = await myFile.readAsLinesSync(); I still get a warning on await: Await only futures so I took out await.

Comment: To display your text on the screen, you just have to save the text that your function reads in a Variable and use this variable in the Text widget.
I think, you can also call your function in the Text widget. Something like:

     child: Text( yourReader.readMyFile()),

Before you can do that, you should modify your function to return a String. Something like:

Future<String> readMyFile() 

In the function readMyFile(), you should add a return statement.

Comment: Sorry, I still can't make it work. I wrote Future<String> readMyFile(), which seemed OK. And after the if block I wrote: return linesAsList; But it said the linesAsList is undefined, which I don't understand since it is in the function readMyFile.

Comment: It seems like you don't read the code and the errors or you don't actually know how to program. I would recommend you to learn how to program first. "linesAsList" is defined in the "if-block". How can you try to call it outside of this block? You have to define it before the "if-block" if you want to call it outside of this block.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to add Esen Mehmet's code to a new file. Suppose you are pressing a button which opens up the text file on a new page, you just need to add the below code in the same class :

```
Future _future;
Future<String> loadString() async =>
await rootBundle.loadString('assets/text.txt');

@override
void initState() {
_future = loadString();
super.initState();
```

And the below code in the body of the scaffold:

```
    FutureBuilder(
future: _future,
builder: (context, snapshot) =>
Text(snapshot.hasData ? '${snapshot.data}' : ' Reading...')),
```

Comment: Yes, that is just what I have done: added that code to each small text file, and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

First this code to have a new screen and call your code:

```
child: 
FlatButton(
  onPressed: () {
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/indled');
    setState(() {
      ReadFile(fileName: 'myfile.txt');
      print('Button 1 got pressed');
    });
    },
    ......
```

It prints Button 1 got pressed on console and goes fine to new screen indled, which has the code:

```
class Indled extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('Indledning'),
  ),
  body: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
    children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Text('Indledning 2'),
```

It prints 'Indledning 2' on the screen as a test, but nothing more happens. I have your code as the following in a separate file:

```
class ReadFile {
ReadFile({this.fileName});

final String fileName;

Future<void> readMyFile() async {
Directory directory = await      getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
var _localFilePath = (directory.path + "myfile.txt");

if (FileSystemEntity.typeSync(_localFilePath) ==
    FileSystemEntityType.file) {
  final myFile = await _localFile(_localFilePath);
  List<String> linesAsList = myFile.readAsLinesSync();

  for (var i = 0; i < linesAsList.length; i++) {
    //print("Line No: " + i.toString() + "\n");
    print(linesAsList[i]);
  }
}
}

Future<File> _localFile(String myPath) async {
return File(myPath);
}
}
```

On the line: List linesAsList = await myFile.readAsLinesSync();
I get a warning on await:  Await only futures
so I took out await. But same result if await is included.

I have tried to put fileName instead of "my file.txt" in your code, but same result.

Comment: I now need to display my small text file in a ListView. The file is still in the assets directory in the app and I would like to use the rootbundle.loadstring command. Can anyone help on how to do this?